# lldb complains about variable named "this"

Tags: xcode, lldb

I'm using Xcode/lldb to debug some C code. But I get this error

```
(lldb) p (int)g_list_position(start, next)
(int) $0 = 1
(lldb) p (int)g_list_position(start, this)
error: expected unqualified-id
error: invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function
```

So apparently lldb things "this" is a reference to a class, in spite of it being a perfectly valid var in C (and its value is 0, as it should be). Is there some way to escape this name in lldb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the expression evaluator in lldb wraps your expression (at at a source level) with some C++ to pass the arguments in.  The only suggestion I can think of is to get the address in the `this` pointer and put that in the expression explicitly.  It's a goal of the expression evaluation that you can copy a line of source in your program and execute it as an expression in lldb .. but this is a corner case where that does not work - variables in C that are reserved words in C++.

Comment: Interesting... ok it's not a big deal, but I figured I'd ask. Ironically, in the pane to the left where it lists the variables I can see it understand "this" just fine.

Comment: Yah, that doesn't go through the expression evaluation (it doesn't go through the compiler), that's a simple variable lookup.  I suspect `p this` will fail.  `v this` (aka `frame variable this`) will succeed because frame variable is doing a simple search for variables with that name in the current scope.  It's the same mechanism that Xcode uses to populate the Locals window.